# Is the use of Objects as keys inefficient in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I define a couple of classes. Then I create object of each class. I want to save the objects in a map keyed by their classes, so that I can retrieve the object based on its class.

*(I'm using ES6 syntax, however the question may remain the same for legacy Javascript with class replaced by function)*

```
// Alternative 1

class Apple {
}

class Banana {
}

let fruitInBag = {};
fruitInBag[Apple] = new Apple();
fruitInBag[Banana] = new Banana();
```

Alternatively I could also write following with the same outcome

```
// Alternative 2

class Apple {
}

class Banana {
}

const FRUIT_TYPE_APPLE = 1;
const FRUIT_TYPE_BANANA = 2;

let fruitInBag = {};
fruitInBag[FRUIT_TYPE_APPLE] = new Apple();
fruitInBag[FRUIT_TYPE_BANANA] = new Banana();
```

The second alternative is awkward, because I've to define and maintain the constants separate from class definitions. Therefore I would prefer the first one. But is the first approach inefficient? Is the `Object` smart enough to implement the first alternative efficiently?

Comment: what about a `Map`? an object will "normalize" its keys to a string representation.

Comment: The key is not class but string with class name.

Comment: What is the concern ? Is question related to _performance_ ?

Comment: I am not super familiar with ES6 syntax but I think that in both examples the identifiers are being set as strings arent they? Specifically `"Apple"`, `"Banana"`, `"FRUIT_TYPE_APPLE "`, and `"FRUIT_TYPE_BANANA "`. In your second example `fruitInBag[FRUIT_TYPE_APPLE]` and `fruitInBag[1]` are undefined but `fruitInBag["FRUIT_TYPE_APPLE"]` is defined

Comment: Neither version works the way you think they do, so comparing them isn't going to get you anywhere.

Comment: @Marie and nnnnnn You are right. I have updated the code in question. The way I had written it before the keys were strings. But now I'm assigning objects or integers as keys explicitly. Check the updated version now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I updated the code snippet in the question to correctly reflect the problem. After having done that and taking the suggestions from the comments and deleted answer, I did some analysis in Chrome devtools as follows.

[image: Map Keys Analysis]

As you can see from the picture, I defined a class in both ES6 (`class Apple`) and ES5 (`function FnApple`) manner. Then I kept them in regular ES5 object (`mapA`) and later ES6 map (`mapB`). In all the cases the browser stringifies the class definition completely and uses that string as a key. This works, because complete stringification of class makes it distinct. (I was afraid the stringification will the a dump `[Object]` string).

However this also means that using the class or function object as key will make the map key of indeterminately long size. In real world scenario when classes have long definitions, the key can go upto few KBs. Given this, it makes sense that one should use independently defined integers for keys in maps.

**Update**

In case of ES6 map, my test above is incorrect. I assigned the key-value to the mapB object using `[]` syntax, which makes it store the key-value as member of object like ES5 (because even ES6 Map instance is an object). The right way to set key-value on ES6 map is to use get(),set() API. After doing that I see that the type of keys is indeed `function` and not `String` for ES6 Map.

[image: Correction]

Comment: A ES6 Map does *not* use strings as keys! It uses the Object itself! Checkout a ES5 polyfill to see that!

Comment: You are right. I know what I did wrong to get that impression. Updating the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Keys in a Javascript object are always strings. No Integers and no functions (Classes). Use a ES6 Map for this!